# Mongodb start error with security.authorization enabled

Tags: macos, mongodb

I am getting an error attempting to start mongo with authorization enabled via the security.authorization configuration parameter (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization)

On running mongod I get

```
Error parsing INI config file: unknown option security.authorization
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Supporting data:

- Mongo version 2.6.0 (installed via homebrew)
- OSX Mavericks 10.9.2

start command:

```
mongod -f /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

mongod.conf file (works fine if I comment out security.authorization):

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

# auth
security.authorization = enabled
#security.authenticationMechanisms = MONGODB-CR  #error occurs with or without this
```

No entry is made in the mongo.log file when this occurs

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** I would have written this as a comment, however I do not have the points yet.

Just wondering whether what you are trying to achieve is *authentication* instead? If this is the case, all you need to set in `mongodb.conf` is:

```
# auth
auth = true   # true or false. Whether or not authentication is required.
```

-- UPDATED:

Some other steps that are important:

**Configure the db location:** Set in `mongodb.conf` as (you already have this, but should check the directory and permissions exist):

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true
```

Dont forget to make sure the above `/usr/local/var/mongodb` directory and `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/` directory exist. The installer that you used may not have made them.

**Create an Operating System user for mongodb:** (If one has not already been created - this is how on linux, not sure for osx) - as root:

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password --group mongodb
```

Add permissions to folders if they are not already set:

```
chown mongodb:mongodb -R /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

**To setup database user authorization / privileges:**

See the command reference here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/#database-commands

Comment: I am just following the docs :) : the Mongodb documentation for enabling _authentication_ tells you to set the _authorization_ setting (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). It doesn't mention any configuration setting called **auth** that I can find. I will give it a go and see if it works.

Comment: I must say that I personally find the docs confusing, I have updated my answer with a bit more info that I hope is useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB server config file format changed from version 2.6 and still old format works.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

> Changed in version 2.6: MongoDB introduces a YAML-based configuration file format. The 2.4 configuration file format remains for backward compatibility.

The error is due to the reason your config file is using old format and adding parameter **security.authorization = enabled** using new format.You can fix the problem by 
 using old format settings mentioned at http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options

> auth = true

or by converting conf file to new YAML format.